# How to pass a member function to a base class contructor?

Tags: c++, function, constructor, member, derived-class

I have a class structure that i want to use and i want to use a function of a derived class to be passed as a constructor argument to the base class. I cannot find the right syntax for it (new to C :))

This is the base class that i use and it has a constructor with a callback function:

```
class SPortSensor {
        public:
            SPortSensor(sensorData (*pCallback)(SPortSensor*));
            sensorData getValue();
        private:
            sensorData (*getData)(SPortSensor*);
    };
```

This is the derived class that implements the callback function within the class (pCallback) so it has a different constructor and a member function that needs to be passed to the base class constructor:

```
    class SimpleSensor : public SPortSensor {
        public: 
            SimpleSensor(int id);
            long value;
        private:
            int _id;
            sensorData pCallback(SPortSensor*);
    };
```

This header compiles fine. The only error i am seeing is in the implementation of the SimpleSensor constructor. I cannot find the right syntax for this:

```
sensorData SimpleSensor::pCallback(SPortSensor* sensor) {
   ...
}

SimpleSensor::SimpleSensor(int id) : SPortSensor(pCallback) {
  _id = id;
}
```

Googling this issue didn't help that much since i probably don't use the right search words and don't understand enough of c++ (i am a C# guy).

Comment: To call `pCallback` of `SimpleSensor` you need both a `SimpleSensor` instance to call it on and a `SPortSensor*` as argument. How would the internals of `SPortSensor` get the first one?

Comment: Looks more like job for polymorphism.

Comment: Can you show what you intend to do with the callback function? It seems likely that there's a really simple solution that doesn't involve manually passing your own function to your parent class. Also, what C++ version/standard are you using (before or after C++11)?

Comment: I am using c++11 (Platform IO / Arduino). Basically the SPortSensor works as it should. It needs a callback function from the application that uses this class so it must be forced using the constructor. I now have a simple version that has the callback function "internally", but i want to re-use the SPortSensor class because it contains more functionality and is used by other classes.

Comment: Would a virtual function work? (It can't be used during the base class constructor, but if you need that there's an issue no matter how you set things up, since the members of the derived class are not yet initialized.)

Comment: Without clarification this is the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). And extremely important pieces are missing, like you are using Arduino (and most of them doesn't support almost anything from STL, so you can't use for example std::function and so on).

Answer (score 1):

The circular reference smells like there might be some general ownership issues.

But, one way around your impass is to use `std::function<sensorData(SPortSensor*)>` instead of the function pointers. Then initialize the base class with a lambda pointing to itself:

```cpp
SimpleSensor(int id) : SPortSensor([this](SPortSensor* sps) { return pCallback(sps); }) { }
```

I cannot in good concious condone this, but it didn't explode when I tried it. One caveat is that SimpleSensor won't be initialized when the base constructor is called, so SPortSensor can't call the lambda in its own constructor.

Comment: How would i replace the member     sensorData (*getData)(SPortSensor*);      for this?

Comment: `std::function<sensorData(SPortSensor*)> getData;`

Comment: It doesn't like that: qualified name is not allowed.

Comment: This is what I tested with: https://godbolt.org/z/2tR9Qi

Out of curiosity though, is there a C# functionality you're trying to replicate here?

Comment: @parktomatomi He's using Arduino, so there is a high probability he doesn't have ARM based one and therefore no std::function and so on. But doesn't mentioned that in the question but in comments later...

Answer (score 0):

Call-backs usually take place between different objects.  One solution is to differ the use of the derived class method after constructor (in an init method for example?), and declare the method as virtual.

```
#include <iostream>

struct sensorData {
    double val = 0;
};

class SPortSensor {
public:
    virtual sensorData getValue() {
        std::cout << "Base class\n";
        sensorData sd;
        return sd;
    }
};

class SimpleSensor : public SPortSensor {
public: 
    long value;
    SimpleSensor(int id): id(id) {
    }
    virtual sensorData getValue() {
        std::cout << "Derived class\n";
        sensorData sd;
        return sd;
    }
private:
    int id;
};


int main() {
    SPortSensor base;
    SimpleSensor derived(1);
    base.getValue();
    derived.getValue();
    SPortSensor* derivedPtr = new SimpleSensor(2);
    derivedPtr->getValue();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The idea to use polymorphy is reasonable/good, but your code snippet has nothing to do with the one in question. It would be much more useful if you could adapt the code in the question to this.

Comment: True, and polymorphy  isn't really an option since my class A doesn't have any implementation of the function.

Comment: @AProgrammer The point of the code is to show that calling a virtual method from the constructor does not work. This why there are two calls, and that I advised the OP to delay the use of the virtual method until after the constructor.

Comment: @HermanKruisman If your base class has no implementation, then you should declare it pure virtual.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Code modified.

Comment: The base class gets the implementation through the constructor from the calling class (is implemented as a function in the calling class). Can you make an example for that?

Comment: @HermanKruisman Virtual methods ensure that the correct method is called independently of the type of the pointer. You have an example above (last three lines of main): calling getValue on the pointer (which is of type SPortSensor, the base class) will result in calling the derived class method. I suggest you take a look at virtual methods, because this is what I believe you need in your case.

Comment: Ok, i just don't get how this works without the derived class (just using the base)

Comment: @HermanKruisman You write the code that uses the method in the base class and implement it in the derived class(es) and you are done. The compiler will automatically call the method of the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

So i think the complexity (issue?) was in trying to do thing with to few lines of code. I simply switched to polymorphy with a abstract class to simplify things.

Abstract base:

```
    class SPortSensor {
        public:
            void (*valueSend)(void);
            virtual sensorData getData () = 0;
    };
```

2 implementation classes:

```
class CustomSPortSensor : public SPortSensor {
        public:
            CustomSPortSensor(sensorData (*callback)(CustomSPortSensor*));
        private:
            sensorData (*_callback)(CustomSPortSensor*);

        virtual sensorData getData(){
            return _callback(this);
        }
    };

    class SimpleSPortSensor : public SPortSensor {
        public: 
            SimpleSPortSensor(int id);
            long value;
        private:
            int _id;

        virtual sensorData getData(){
            sensorData data;
            data.sensorId = _id;
            data.value = value;
            return data;
        }
    };
```

This now works as expected and is very easy to use and understand (usage of the implementation must as readable as possible).

Now i only want the implementation of the virtual functions to be in the .cpp instead of the .h.......